# Passing multiple argument to ng-click method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my code i like to pass to arguments to the function specified inside the ng-click attribute.

```
<div class="shout" ng-repeat="user in users">
 <p>{{user.name}}</p>
 <img src="media/images/delete.png" ng-click="deleteUser({{$index}},{{user._id}})"/>
</div>
```

and in the controller

```
function deleteUser(index, userId){...}
```

the parameter index is to remove the user from $scope.user and user._id to remove it from the mongodb. i am a newbee to angular js.

when i tried like this the deleteUser is not getting called. if i pass single argument it works like charm but when i pass more than its not working

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You don't need `{{ }}` while specifying arguments to an event handlers (`ng-click`). The correct syntax would be `ng-click="deleteUser($index, user._id)`:

```
<div class="shout" ng-repeat="user in users">
 <p>{{user.name}}</p>
 <img src="media/images/delete.png" ng-click="deleteUser($index, user._id)"/>
</div>
```

Here is a working plunker based on the code you've provided (check the console to see that click handler is working correctly): http://plnkr.co/edit/26A4Rj0FScPXYU7z92E6?p=preview

Comment: it tried like this ng-click="deleteUser($index, user._id)" but in the rendered code it shows deleteUser($index,user_id) the values not get binded.

Comment: @JaisonJustus not sure what is not working for you, so I've attached a plunk with the live code. Maybe it was a way in which you define a function in a scope?

Comment: keep space after the "," between parameters of deleteUser() function is the key here. Thnks for the tip