# Copy an item from an array to another array on click event in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a list of food items. The food items are made from JSON files read into an array called `$scope.foodlist`. 
Each food item has a checkbox called "favourite". When it's checked I want to make a copy of the food item and place it in a separate div called "favourites". I suspect the best way to do this will be to have an array `$scope.favourites` and to add a food item to this array when its checkbox is clicked, and remove it when its checkbox is not clicked.

On the checkbox, I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="addFavourite($event)" />
```

Right now, for the function I have this:

```
 $scope.addFavourite = function(event) {
   $scope.clicked= "clicked";
 };
```

This prints out the word "clicked" to `{{ clicked }}` in the template.

How can I pass the knowledge of which food item has just been clicked, to the function `addFavourite()`?

[Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9J73vQwsYzt4V5TLkpLb?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some guys provided a tutorial how to deal with checkboxes in AngularJS:

- Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14520103/1477415
- Tutorial http://jsbin.com/ImAqUC/1

Answer (score 0):

Just pass extra argument to addFavourite function. Here is an example:
[Passing multiple argument to ng-click method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605926/passing-multiple-argument-to-ng-click-method)