# Angular2 - pass dynamically loaded parameters to function while doing dropdown value selection

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

Please check that, I am passing the parameters of **li** tag **click** function of **updateId** method in the correct format or not ? The errors in the console shows that line only....

My app.component.html code is

```
<div class='form-group' style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="width : 75%;text-align: left;">{{name}}</button>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"><span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 75%;">
             <li *ngFor="let result of jsonList" ><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="updateId('{{result.id}}', '{{result.name}}')" >{{result.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My app.component.ts is ,

```
import { HomeService } from '../../services/home.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-component',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  id: string;
  name : string;
  jsonList : any;

  constructor(private homeservice: HomeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = null;
    this.name = "SELECT";
    this.jsonList= [{"Id" : "F1", "name" : "FONE"}, {"id" : "F2", "name" : "FTWO"}]
  }



  updateId(id : string, name : string) : void {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
  }

}
```

It is not working. The error is on the **li**  tag **click** function method passing the dynamic parameters from the **jsonList**. So pls help me to get resolve.

Comment: What is the error? And is this a typo: `this .name` ?

Comment: Help us help you by telling us the error you are getting, what you expect to happen and what you are getting instead. You can't just post code say it doesn't work and hope for the best. You need to provide information so people know where to look.

Comment: @nbo.... Changed it and edited the question..... Now pls check it.

Comment: Please be careful with your tag selections.  AngularJS has **nothing** to do with Angular2, they are completely different frameworks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing multiple argument to ng-click method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605926/passing-multiple-argument-to-ng-click-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the handlebars `{{ }}` in event bindings such as the `(click)` attribute - they will be evaluated against the Component instance automatically. and the single quotes are not needed either. Use it like so:

```
<li *ngFor="let result of jsonList">
    <a (click)="updateId(result.id, result.name)">{{result.name}}</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need {{ }} while specifying arguments to an event handlers (ng-click). The correct syntax would be

```
<li *ngFor="let result of jsonList">
    <a (click)="updateId(result.id, result.name)">{{result.name}}</a>
</li>
```